# VRPTW: How to handle time windows and slacks for the special depot node?

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I find reading all values of an assignment, obtained from

```
assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_params)
```

of routing problems with time windows quiet tricky. First of all, there are nodes and indices. I obtain the indices of a vehicle (route) via

```
index = routing.Start(vehicle)
indices = [index]
while not routing.IsEnd(index):
    index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
    indices.append(index)
```

and the corresponding nodes are obtained by

```
nodes = [routing.IndexToNode(x) for x in indices]
```

For a particular routing problem with 5 stops and `depot=0` the solver finds an assignment with the following indices and nodes:

```
vehicle: 0
indices: [0, 1, 6]
nodes:   [0, 1, 0]

vehicle: 1
indices: [5, 4, 3, 2, 7]
nodes:   [0, 4, 3, 2, 0]
```

So there are three more indices than nodes, because each vehicle starts and ends in the depot. I have defined a cost of 1 for every transit and reading the cost values via

```
cost_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("cost")
cost_vars = [cost_dimension.CumulVar(x) for x in indices]
costs = [assignment.Value(x) for x in cost_vars]
```

seems to work:

```
vehicle: 0
indices: [0, 1, 6]
nodes:   [0, 1, 0]
costs:   [0, 1, 2]

vehicle: 1
indices: [5, 4, 3, 2, 7]
nodes:   [0, 4, 3, 2, 0]
costs:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But when I add time constraints I run into problems. Let's first look at the code that defines the problem. The time unit is minutes.

```
def time_function(x,y):
    return 30

evaluator = time_function
slack_max = 40
capacity = 24*60
fix_start_cumul_to_zero = False
name = "time"
routing.AddDimension(evaluator, slack_max, capacity, fix_start_cumul_to_zero, name)
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("time")

time_windows = [(7*60, 8*60),(9*60, 10*60),(9*60, 10*60),
                (9*60, 10*60),(9*60, 10*60)]
for node, time_window in enumerate(time_windows):
    time_dimension.CumulVar(node).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
    routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(node))
```

So each trip takes 30 minutes, vehicles may be idle at a stop for 40 minutes (`slack_max=40`) and each stop should be serviced between 9am and 10am. The range constraints that are enforced via `time_windows[0]` are intended to define the starting times of each trip in the morning. But since the depot is the first *and* last stop of each route they could also be interpreted as arriving times in the evening.

So here is my first difficulty with time windows: the depot appears twice on each route but the range constraint is defined on nodes. I am assuming that the routing model is not designed to take two windows for the depot?

Let me continue to get to the second part of my question. I set `fix_start_cumul_to_zero = False` so that routes may start at any time. Also note that `routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(node))` is supposed to give me access to the slack variables later. Now, when I inspect the time values per index, via

```
time_vars = [time_dimension.CumulVar(x) for x in indices]
times.append([assignment.Value(x) for x in time_vars])
```

formated with datetime, I get reasonable results:

```
vehicle: 0
indices: [0, 1, 6]
nodes:   [0, 1, 0]
costs:   [0, 1, 2]
times:   ['7:50:00', '9:00:00', '9:30:00']

vehicle: 1
indices: [5, 4, 3, 2, 7]
nodes:   [0, 4, 3, 2, 0]
costs:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
times:   ['7:50:00', '9:00:00', '9:30:00', '10:00:00', '10:30:00']
```

The solver apparently favors early departure times. Given the max slack of 40min, each vehicle might also start a bit later, e.g. at 8am.

The trouble begins when I try to read the slack variables via

```
slack_vars = [time_dimension.SlackVar(x) for x in indices]
slacks = [assignment.Value(x) for x in slack_vars]
```

The program crashes with the message:

> SystemError:  returned NULL
>   without setting an error

which suggests that `time_dimension` does not have a slack variable for every index. Is that right? Why not?

Thanks for reading this excessive post. Here are the two questions:

1. Is it possible to define arrival and departure time windows for the depot?
2. How to properly read the slacks for time windows for all nodes, including the depo?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer question 2 first, since 1 is a guess from this answer...

2) First, Slack variable is only needed if you have a next node so there is not slack var for the end node.
basically `if j is next(i) then cumul(j) = cumul(i) + transit(i,j) + slack(i)`

You must use "index" not "node_index" for accessing/setting SlackVar.
i.e. there is `N` node_index (i.e. N locations including the depot) but
`M = N-1/*depot*/ + num_vehicle*2 /*Start, End for each vehicle*/` index
i.e. each vehicle has a specific objet instance for its start and end node 
 -> that's why you nee to use routing.Start(i) to get the "start" index of the i-th vehicle (e.d.: in fact NodeToIndex(0) give you the start index for the vehicle 0).

```python
def add_time_window_constraints(routing, data, time_evaluator):
    """Add Global Span constraint"""
    time = "Time"
    horizon = 120
    routing.AddDimension(
        time_evaluator,
        horizon, # allow waiting time
        horizon, # maximum time per vehicle
        True, # start cumul to zero
        time)
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data.time_windows):
        if location_idx == 0:
            continue
        time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.NodeToIndex(location_idx)).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
        routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(routing.NodeToIndex(location_idx)))
    for vehicle_id in xrange(data.num_vehicles):
        routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(routing.Start(vehicle_id)))
        # slack not defined for vehicle ends
        #routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(self.routing.End(vehicle_id)))
```

1) /!\ NOT TESTED /!\
For time windows for departure I would use:

```
for vehicle_id in xrange(data.num_vehicles):
    time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(vehicle_id)).SetRange(begin, end)
```

/!\ you must set `cumul_start_to_zero` to False when creating the dimension if begin if > 0 otherwise it won't find a solution obviously /!\

i.e. You have to set it for each vehicle...

Your code barely work because `node_index == index` for the first nodes then it start to crash....

ps: I'm working on fixing the doc and examples for the index/node_index usage

Full example and tracked issue in [google/or-tools #708](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/708).
ps: Thanks for having spotted this issue ;)